# Average age to start a PhD and correlation to future career

Tags: phd, age

Which is the average age in which persons start their PhD? Is this age in some way related to the post PhD plans a person does?

In my (European) experience I have 3 groups of people, with the relative distributions:

1. (70% of the total) Those who started right after graduation (let's say when they were 24) without any job experience. Most of them (with exceptions, of course) are a bit fed up with research and willing to try a "real world job experience"
2. (25% of the total) Those who started 2,3,4 years later (so between 24 and 29), taking a full time phd. Generally people belonging to this group seem to be more motivated for academic career, even if starting a phd when one is 29 years old might be a bit late (or not?)
3. (5%) Those who start in their 40ties with the idea of taking a part time PhD as an out of job activity, and don't plan to leave their job.

Clearly there are all the possible shades between the above categories.

Comment: This seems to be a case of "71% of all statistics are made up on the spot". Anyway, independently of your numbers, it would make sense to me if people who have worked in industry for a few years but decided it is not for them are less likely to long for "real-world experience" than those that never made this experience so far.

Comment: I imagine it depends a lot on the field.  For example, a Ph.D. program in medieval literature, where there is little or no prospect of getting a job afterward, may have a lot of those 40-year-olds.

Comment: @xLeitix And [93.7% of people believe them whether they are accurate statistics or not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUK6zjtUj00).

Comment: @OP, it's not clear what you mean by "started" in some parts of the question. E.g., "started right after graduation (let's say when they were 24)" == graduation from bachelor's program? master's? In my day, you were graduated with BA or BS at age 21 or 22 after 4 years, or MA/MS at 22-24 after 1 or 2 more years, if you weren't going directly into the doctoral program. Starting at 24 would generally be after a couple years in the workforce.

Comment: @shoover  OP is talking about Europe. Here universities often require a master to enroll in a PhD programme, and studying towards your master usually takes at least 5 years. So no, starting a PhD at 24 is usually pretty much directly after what is considered the "undergrad" around here.

Comment: @xLeitix Thanks, I missed the "(European)" when I read the q.

Answer (score 21):

There are many confounding variables (field of study, country, citizenship status, sex, race/ethnicity, probably many others) that correlate with both age at doctorate (as seen below) and post-PhD plans. This makes it difficult to directly measure the relationship between age and post-PhD plans.

The median age at doctorate varies by country and by field. Here's some [OECD data](http://www.uis.unesco.org/ScienceTechnology/Documents/44893058.pdf):

[image]

It also varies over time. In the US, from 1978-2003, in the science and engineering fields:

[image]

And in the non-science and engineering fields:

[image]

See [this report](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/infbrief/nsf06312/nsf06312.pdf) for more details.

For the US, we have [data](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsf16300/data/tab27.pdf) on the distribution of students' age, not just the median, and it's also broken down by  sex, citizenship status, and ethnicity and race.  From 2014:

[image]

Comment: While strong data for the first part, this is missing the "correlation to future career" part, which I feel is what the OP is really after.

Comment: @xLeitix This is why we have the [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se/1204#1204) rule.

Comment: If you're going to answer exactly one part of the question, and you're going to justify it by saying that asking two questions is a violation of cite policy, shouldn't you edit away all references to the other question in the OP? Otherwise we'll be permanently left with a dangling unanswered question that can't be asked again lest it be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Can we subtract the median age at doctorate by the total time to degree to get the median age at PhD start like the question asks?

Comment: @Sam: No, not really.  They aren't uncorrelated.